# What is the difference in memory allocation of objects extending AnyVal and AnyRef

Tags: java, scala, memory-management

So in Java we see that primitive types take up less memory space than their object counterparts. For example an `int` will take less space than an instance of `Integer`.
For which reason its often more sensible to `char` instead of `String` to store single characters.

I want to understand how does this translate to Scala.
There are no primitives. All we have are instances of `AnyVal` or `AnyRef`.
Is there are difference between the memory allocations for each ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there are difference between the memory allocations for each

`AnyRef` is similar to inherting `object`, where you get the normal overhead of 8/16 bytes for x86/x64 respectively for every object because of headers.

`AnyVal` in Scala allows to optimize a very specific use case where you have a single `val` parameter which is wrapped in a `class`, and you can represent the said class as the underlying value at runtime, instead of allocating an instance of the class.

`AnyVal` has several restrictions:

> 1. Must have only a primary constructor with exactly one public, val parameter whose type is not a value class. (From Scala 2.11.0, the
>      parameter may be non-public.)
> 2. May not have specialized type parameters.
> 3. May not have nested or local classes, traits, or objects
> 4. May not define a equals or hashCode method.
> 5. Must be a top-level class or a member of a statically accessible object
> 6. Can only have defs as members. In particular, it cannot have lazy vals, vars, or vals as members.
> 7. Cannot be extended by another class.

For example, if we take the example [from the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

```
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def foo: Wrapper = new Wrapper(underlying * 19)
}
```

The representation of `Wrapper` at compile time is still a class. But at runtime, the underlying representation will be an `Int`, instead of a class `Wrapper` with an additional `Int` field.

But it isn't always guaranteed that `Wrapper` will become an `Int` representation at runtime. It won't when:

1. A value class is treated as another type.
2. A value class is assigned to an array.
3. Doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Just thinking out loud .So in case of declarations like `val a:Int`      the Int value class is used to allocate memory. ok Thanks man !

Comment: No, in the case of `val a: Int`, there is no object allocation, at least not on the JVM port of the compiler. On the JVM port, `a` will be a JVM primitive `int`. I believe, on the ECMAScript port (Scala.JS), it will be an ECMAScript primitive `Number`. On the (no longer maintained) CLI port, it would have been a `System.Int32` value type. And on the various prototype native ports, it's probably going to be a machine integer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag <--- What he said :)

Comment: That's a lot of knowledge. Thanks everyone for all the priceless inputs. Can you recommend me any way to study what approach to follow to be more careful about memory when writing scala programs. I am not looking for a concrete answer. Just some pointers on how to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there are actually primitives. Scala is just (intentionally) trying to hide the difference.

There are actually 4 cases, not 2:

1. Classes extending `AnyRef`. They are just usual Java-style classes and have the same memory use.
2. `Unit`. It corresponds to Java `void` and is thus often not represented at runtime at all. When it is, `BoxedUnit` class is used.
3. `Int`, `Boolean`, etc. While they look like classes to Scala code, they are normally represented as JVM primitives. But there are certain cases where they can't be and the boxed types (`Integer`, etc.) are used instead. Namely, when they are arguments of generic types/methods *except* for `Array`.
4. User-defined value classes. See Yuval Itzchakov's answer for that. Of course, if you have a value class wrapping a primitive, it ends up being represented as a primitive itself. Note that they aren't *always* represented at the runtime as the underlying type, and in particular it fails for `Array[ValueClass]`, opposite to case 3.

Answer (score 2):

In **Scala**, **Scala** use **box/unbox** [BoxesRunTime.java](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.java) in compile time to deal primitive type:

- box means parse the primitive type to reference type

**byte code**:

```
def foo[T](v: T) = v.toString
def bar(i: Int)= foo(i)
:javap -c bar
public java.lang.String bar(int);
  Code:
     0: getstatic     #19                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
     3: iload_1
     4: invokestatic  #25                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     7: invokevirtual #29                 // Method .foo:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    10: areturn
```

In the above byte code in `bar` method, it box **primitive int type** to **Int reference type**. this is caused we are use primitive type `int` for generics `T`.

- unbox means parse **reference type** to **primitive type**

**byte code:**

```
 def foo(i: Int) = i
    def bar[T](i: T) = foo(i.asInstanceOf[Int])
    public <T> int bar(T);
     Code:
        0: getstatic     #19                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
        3: aload_1
        4: invokestatic  #24                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        7: invokevirtual #28                 // Method .foo:(I)I
```

In the above byte code for bar method, we are parsing a **reference type** to **primitive Int type**, so need to unbox it to **primitive type int**.

so In the runtime, always there are box or unbox for type parse. it maybe will cause bad performance and consume more memory. but we can avoid it by:

- [Value-class](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#value-class) with **AnyVal**
- [specialized annotation](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#specialized)
- [miniboxing](http://scala-miniboxing.org/)

They are all used to solve **box/unbox** problem in **scala**.